# ASP.NET MVC 3 binding making sure form values take priority

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

With a POST request in case it has the same parameter in the query string and in the body of the request which one takes priority with model binding?

Comment: If you're finding this to be an issue and can't change your parameter names, you can look into Custom Model Binding: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=584

Comment: Thank you, I may consider that, need to be sure I get the values from the body and not from query string

Answer (score 7):

From [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx), in the "Value Provders" section.

1. Previously bound action parameters, when the action is a child action
2. Form fields (Request.Form)
3. The property values in the JSON Request body (Request.InputStream), but only when the request is an   AJAX request
4. Route data (RouteData.Values)
5. Querystring parameters (Request.QueryString)
6. Posted files (Request.Files)

So if the same name appears in multiple places, the last place the model binder looks will take precedence (I think), in your case, the querystring.

Easiest thing to do is try it. Enter a url with a &id=23" and make sure you have a HTML input field named "id" and POST that back to the controller and see which one is passed.

Comment: Turns out the form fields take precedence. I've tested with MVC 3 may be different with other versions

Comment: Just tested it in MVC 5.1.  Form fields take precedence over URL query strings.

Comment: @JohnnyO Cheers for the update. I've been unable to find any documentation about that change, so thanks for pointing it out.